# How to read data in paragraph form in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in this format for several years with each new year separated by a blank line:

```
    2014
    #34 - Show Title
    Ensemble: ActorFirst1 ActorLast1, ActorFirst2 ActorLast2, ActorFirst3 ActorLast3, ActorFirst4 ActorLast4, ActorFirst5 ActorLast5, ActorFirst6 ActorLast6, and ActorFirst7 ActorLast7
    Director: DirectorFirst1 DirectorLast1
    Music Director: MDFirst1 MDFirst1
    Stage Manager: SMFirst1 SMFirst1
    Producer: ProducerFirst1 ProducerFirst1
    Opening Night: December 16, 2014
```

And I'm trying to make it into the form of rows in a dataframe like

Year, PersonFirst1 PersonLast1, Title, Show Title

I have no idea how to do this and keep going down dead ends.

Comment: You should post your expected output from the example. It's not clear what PersonFirst1 is.

Comment: Sorry. I just meant that everyone named is a person. I want their first and last name along with title, one row per person that is in the data.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't quite say exactly how your data were stored, so I'll assume you have a bunch of items similar to the one from above that you get by reading in a file and splitting on newlines. This gives you a string like your example data.

Pass that string to a function:

```
def read_year(f):
    f = iter(f.split('\n'))  # split the string, going to iterate over it

    year = next(f).strip()
    title = next(f).strip()  # maybe split at the '-', dunno if that's part of the title

    # don't need opening date, so iterate till we get there.
    people = takewhile(lambda x: not x.strip().startswith('Opening'), f)
    # setting up for getting (kind, individual)
    people = (tuple(x.split(':')) for x in people) 

    both = []
    for kind, persons in people:
        kind_ = kind.strip()
        for person in persons.strip().split(' '):
            if person != 'and':
                both.append((kind_, person.strip().strip(',')))

    df = pd.DataFrame(both, columns=['person_title', 'person'])
    df['year'] = int(year)
    df['movie_title'] = title
    return df
```

Basically you'll call that function on each string to get

```
In [153]: df = read_year(s)

In [154]: df.head()
Out[154]: 
  person_title       person  year       movie_title
0     Ensemble  ActorFirst1  2014  #34 - Show Title
1     Ensemble   ActorLast1  2014  #34 - Show Title
2     Ensemble  ActorFirst2  2014  #34 - Show Title
3     Ensemble   ActorLast2  2014  #34 - Show Title
4     Ensemble  ActorFirst3  2014  #34 - Show Title
```

Then `pd.concat` those together with `ignore_index=True`.